# How do I edit the /etc/hosts file in fabric python library?

Tags: python

I want to ensure an entry in the /etc/hosts file on all target hosts is correct in the /etc/hosts file with the [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Fabric, when you execute a task, you can access the current host with `env.host`.

Thus, let's assume you configured your `env` variable properly, with its list of hosts:

- Create a dictionary which will map each host with the expected value of the entry you want to check: `check = {host1: value1, host2: value2 ,... }`
- In your Fabric task, simply check if `result_from_etchosts_parsing == check[env.host]`